# Which Interfaces/Services does ASP MVC3 attempt to resolve automatically using DependencyResolver?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, ioc-container

I suppose I could look through the whole MVC3 source and try and find them all, but is there a list somewhere detailing all the Interfaces that MVC3 attempts to resolve automatically using the DependencyResolver?

So far I only have `IControllerFactory`which I'm using to find Controllers using MEF. What other useful services are discovered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Brad Wilson who implemented the DI feature has an entire [blog series about all the services that are retrieved through DependencyResolver in ASP.NET MVC 3](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2010/07/service-location-pt1-introduction.html).